# use 2 commandbars in my UWP app

Tags: uwp-xaml

I want to use 2 command bars in my app. It goes like one in the page and another inside a Frame. The problem is it won't span across the region. the mainpage.xaml is shown below

```
    <Page x:Name="page"
x:Class="TakeOrGive.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TakeOrGive"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RightFrame.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainPivot.Width" Value="320"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="RightFrame.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainPivot.Width" Value="520"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <RelativePanel>
        <RelativePanel Name="RelMain" Height="{Binding Width, ElementName=page}">
            <Pivot Name="MainPivot" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,10,0">
                <PivotItem Header="Unpaid">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="UnpaidStack">
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Name="TotalEx" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="Paid">
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="PaidStack">
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Name="PaidSum" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </RelativePanel>
        <Frame Name="RightFrame" MinWidth="900" MaxWidth="1000" Visibility="Collapsed" RelativePanel.RightOf="RelMain" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=grid}"></Frame>
        <CommandBar RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=MainPivot}" >
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add Entry" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
        </CommandBar>

    </RelativePanel>

</Grid>
<!-- <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add Entry" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>-->
```

[image: Full Screen]

[image: Mobie Size]

Page inside Frame is

```
<Page x:Name="page"
x:Class="TakeOrGive.ViewItems"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TakeOrGive"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <StackPanel>
    <RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel" MinWidth="600" MaxWidth="1000" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=page}">
        <StackPanel Padding="10" Name="MainStack" MinWidth="600">
            <TextBlock FontSize="36" Text="View" MinWidth="800"/>
            <TextBlock Name="TOL" FontSize="20" Text="To:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="ToText"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Amount:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="AmountText"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Income/ToGive:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="TOG"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="When:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="DatePick"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Where:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="WhereText"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Is Paid:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="ispaid"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Detail:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Height="150" Name="DescripText"/>
        </StackPanel>
    <!--    <CommandBar Name="COM1" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Contact" Label="View Person" Click="AppBarButton_Click_2"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" Click="AppBarButton_Click"></AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="OK" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
        </CommandBar>-->
    </RelativePanel>
    <CommandBar Name="COM1">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Contact" Label="View Person" Click="AppBarButton_Click_2"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" Click="AppBarButton_Click"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="OK" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
    </CommandBar>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
<!--<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Contact" Label="View Person" Click="AppBarButton_Click_2"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" Click="AppBarButton_Click"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="OK" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>-->
</Page>
```

Data will be put to stackpanels from backend.
The problem with page.BottomAppbar is it will have only one command bar not 2.
i tried binding with width of page Panels but nothing works
[image: I want like this.]
[image: Another sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use 2 command bars in my app. It goes like one in the page and another inside a Frame. The problem is it won't span across the region. the mainpage.xaml is shown below.

The problem is you have not set relatively complete position constraint. For your requirement, you could use the follow xaml as `CommandBar` constraint.

```
<CommandBar 
    RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.LeftOf="RightFrame" >
    <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add Entry" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
</CommandBar>
```

**Update**

The following code is inside page.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <StackPanel>
        <RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel" MinWidth="600" MaxWidth="1000" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=page}">
            <StackPanel Padding="10" Name="MainStack" MinWidth="600">
                <TextBlock FontSize="36" Text="View" MinWidth="800"/>
                <TextBlock Name="TOL" FontSize="20" Text="To:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="ToText"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Amount:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="AmountText"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Income/ToGive:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="TOG"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="When:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="DatePick"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Where:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="WhereText"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Is Paid:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="ispaid"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Detail:"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Height="150" Name="DescripText"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </RelativePanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <CommandBar Name="COM1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Contact" Label="View Person" Click="AppBarButton_Click_2"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" Click="AppBarButton_Click"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="OK" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Grid>
```

I have use `RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"` to replace height binding.

```
<CommandBar 
    RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.LeftOf="RightFrame" >
    <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add Entry" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
</CommandBar>
<Frame Name="RightFrame" MinWidth="500"  
       MaxWidth="1000" Visibility="Collapsed" 
       RelativePanel.RightOf="RelMain" 
       RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
</Frame>
```

[image]

Comment: Still it is not fitting properly

Comment: How did apps like windows central, mytube etc do that?

Comment: I think you could post some screenshot that you want to realize.

Comment: I want both(one in mainPage and another in ViewPage inside frame) comandbars to take full width and place down at bottom